# как построить тунель за нат

Tags: ssh, nat, putty, tunnel

задача сделать порт виндовой машины за натом, доступным с интернета, есть сервак с линуксом и статическим ip, можно ли как то пробросить порт?

Comment: iptables курите.
Что-то в духе
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.107 -p tcp --dport 89 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.107

Answer (score 1):

SSH позволяет открывать слушающий сокет на стороне сервера.

В настройках PuTTY Conection -> SSH -> Tunnels можно настроить туннель, который будет перенаправлять входящие соединения с сервера на указанный адрес.

Для командной строки параметры туннеля задаются ключём `-R`

[image: Conection -> SSH -> Tunnels]

Comment: я эт давно сделал но оно с виду не работало оказалось что если на локал хост на серваке шимитьса то все ок а если на внешний интерфейс через который собственно законектилса путей то херас два. почему та может быть и как с этим борца?

Comment: нашел 
GatewayPorts yes 
(in /etc/sshd_config)

Comment: @ergo то что вы уже пробовали следует добавлять в вопрос